# How to close a specific process with a specific document in c#

Tags: c#

I want to close a specific process with a specific document in c#

example. I opened a two pdf file

`pdf1.pdf` and `pdf2.pdf`

what I want is close only the pdf2.pdf

I have a code to close a specific program

```
Process[] prs = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process pr in prs)
{
    if (pr.ProcessName == "Foxit Reader")
    {
         pr.Kill();
    }
}
```

But the down side of this is it closes the program and the other files.

and I need to know all the program names that views pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the `MainWindowTitle` to close a particular window instead. Also, close the main window and not kill the process in order to keep the others opened. For example:

```
Process[] prs = Process.GetProcesses();    
foreach (Process pr in prs)
{
     if (pr.MainWindowTitle == "pdf2.pdf - Foxit Reader") // confirm what your window title is
     {
          pr.CloseMainWindow();
     }
}
```

You should be able to find the window title at the top left corner of your opened pdf window.